# Indices statistics is not updateted in a Amazon Aurora read replica

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-replication, amazon-aurora

When I inserted a data, writer DB Indices statistics is updateted.
But, Reader DB Indices statistics is not updateted.

Sample is Here.

database.

```
create database test;
```

table.

```
CREATE TABLE test(
test_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
test_txt CHAR(8) DEFAULT NULL,
INDEX test_txt(test_txt)
);
```

writer.

```
mysql> insert into test values(1, 'test1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> show index from test;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | test_id     | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| test  |          1 | test_txt |            1 | test_txt    | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

reader.

```
mysql> show index from test;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| test  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | test_id     | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| test  |          1 | test_txt |            1 | test_txt    | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why cardinality is not updated only reader??
parameter group is default.

please tell me the reason why.

Comment: Does a `SELECT` from the table on the read replica cause the index stats to update?  Or do they remain the same even after that?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Yes, I issue a SELECT statement from the table on the read replica,
and they still be not updateted.

Comment: I found the article, such as:  
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-14.html  
Excerpt →
InnoDB: Persistent stats would be disabled unnecessarily when running in read-only mode. 
When running in read-only mode, fetching stats from disk does not involve any modification of on-disk data except for when ANALYZE TABLE is run. 
This fix enables persistent stats for read-only mode. (Bug #16083211)

Comment: and I investigated aurora version.

    mysql> select version();
    +-----------+
    | version() |
    +-----------+
    | 5.6.10    |
    +-----------+
    1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Therefore, I suspect this is bug.